# ActionScript 3 / Flex 4 : Add Text/Label to an Image loading in AS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I load an image from a url and add it to the stage.

I need a way to add some text to the image before loading it to the stage !

NOTE: add text over the image after it has been loaded

thanks in advance.

NOTE:
Image type  mx : Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a composite component then. 
Any with absolute positioning should do.

Just make sure to add the label as the last subcomponent.

For example:

```
<mx:Canvas width="100" height="100">
    <mx:Image source="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <s:Label text="This is your text"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: *Technically*, this doesn't add the text to the `Image` itself but just displays the text over the `Image`. This may or may not be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is indeed a quick fix for the problem described.
If it is really necessary to incorporate a watermark in the image, then some server side technology would be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Because I don't want to use another side service to do something , this is the best way to go ahead and do this.

thanks Jason and Dennis for your time